# Como evitar acceso a archivo .js desde el navegador

Tags: javascript, html, seguridad

Tengo el siguiente escenario:

> Tengo un sitio web que clásicamente utiliza archivos .js, el problema es que si desde el navegador acceso directamente a la url del .js se puede visualizar todo el código de dicho archivo, por ejemplo si acceso a http://sitioweb.com/archivo.js, todo el codigo java script del archivo.js se muestra en el navegador, lo que quiero es que no se pueda acceder al archivo desde la url directamente ya que estos archivos .js pueden tener información confidencial.

Se que el archivo .js a la larga si o si tiene que descargarse al navegador para su ejecutar sus funciones, pero quiero evitar el acceso directo a dicho archivo.

Saludos.

Comment: Puedes intentar ofuscando tu código, te dejo [aquí](https://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx) un simple ejemplo de ello

Comment: Gracias por el dato JoriusR, efectivamente ya realice eso, pero como dije necesito que no se pueda acceder directamente a al .js desde el navegador, por ahi me comentaron que tal vez se pueda hacer algo en el IIS.

Comment: En que lenguaje estas desarrollando el `backend`?

Comment: Obviamente javascript Marcos, si es un archivo _.js_

Comment: el back en asp.net (vb.net, framwork 1.1 de visual studio 2003) - (Es software heredado :( )

Comment: Lo ideal es que el código javascript no tenga datos con información confidencial, ya que principalmente es utilizado para darle dinamismo a la página, todas las validaciones que tengas o esa información confidencial, escribela en el asp.net en vez de mandarlo al Javascript.

Comment: OK entendido, pero tengo este escenario: Tengo un login, del cual el pass debe estar encriptado, esta pass no debe viajar el texto claro hacia el servidor, es por eso que se utiliza un archivo .js para encriptar el pass, una vez encriptado recien viaja al servidor, es por eso que la confidencialidad de este .js es critico. Bueno imagino que no debo estar tomando el mejor camino, pero entonces como lo hago? ya que como ya lo dije la contraseña no debe viajar en claro desde el cliente hacia el servidor.

Comment: @RSillerico esto que estás comentando: "*¿cómo hacer para que la encriptación no quede al descubierto al leer el javascript?*" podría ser una buena pregunta para realizar en otra publicación... eso sí, teniendo mucho cuidado de que no sea una pregunta demasiado amplia ni basada en opiniones (leyendo bien toda la ayuda antes de preguntar, para evitar que sea puesta en espera)

Comment: Voy a dar mi opinion. Creo deberia enfocar el asunto desde otra arista. Una contraseña en un archivo js?no   entiendo. La idea es usar https, te garantizaría una conexión segura entre cliente y servidor, no crees?

Answer (score 3):

No es posible evitar el acceso al archivo ya que si lo haces el navegador no podrá ejecutarlo. Por otra parte si logras que bajo ciertas características (como un user_agent) un usuario no pueda ver el js directamente y el navegador si, no sera muy complicado saltarse el filtro ya que hay un acceso concedido.

Para garantizar el cifrado de las contraseñas desde un punto A (js) al punto B (asp.net) se debe de usar el protocolo https que se encarga de cifrar todo el contenido compartido entre el punto A y el punto B siempre y cuando ambos usen el cifrado.

Te recomiendo revisar [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) que permite agregar certificados ssl de forma gratuita, aunque siempre esta la posibilidad de comprarlos, desconozco como estas desplegando tus aplicaciones pero normalmente los proveedores cuenta con la opción de agregar ssl a tus servidores.

Answer (score 2):

Es posible lograr este objetivo en parte aunque tiene grandes desventajas de performance tanto para el cliente como para el servidor.

**Sistema de tokens unicos**

Tendrias que utilizar un lenguaje del lado del servidor (PHP, ASP, etc) para servir archivos JS validando con un token unico, este token debe expirar en el momento en que se sirve el archivo.

1.- Generar un token unico en la carga de la pagina web, guardarlo (bd, filesystem, etc) e incluirlo en tu HTML de la siguiente forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.php?token=asdfa377f32fasdf8283f23f283f23"></script>
```

2.- Crea el programa js.php donde deberias validar si este token existe, en caso de que exista servirias el archivo js y eliminarias el token.

Con esta logica lo que logramos es que la primera vez que se carga la pagina web el cliente haria un request contra js.php enviando el token correspondiente, el programa serviria el archivo JS y eliminaria el token. Para cuando el usuario vea el codigo fuente y trate de acceder a este script el token ya no existiria y por ende no podria ver el codigo fuente del script.

**Aclaraciones**

Cabe aclarar que con esto solo logramos que el usuario no pueda acceder directamente al codigo fuente usando la URL del script pero con cualquier consola de desarrollo de navegadores web recientes se puede depurar el script visualizando todo el codigo fuente que ya esta cargado en el navegador web. Javascript es un lenguaje que se ejecuta del lado del cliente y por ende nunca se deben guardar datos confidenciales en ellos, cualquier dato confidencial debe guardarse en el servidor y nunca ser servido al cliente sin algun tipo de encriptacion.

Independientemente de que esta logica solo soluciona una parte de la problematica puede generar un gran problema de performance tanto en el servidor como en el cliente ya que cada visita a esta url generara un nuevo request contra el servidor para validar el token unico; Por ende, perderias la posibilidad de tener tus archivos javascript cacheados en el navegador obligando al cliente a descargar nuevos archivos javascript con cada visita y generando un esfuerzo extra en el servidor por manejar mas cantidad de requests.